# convert a table of 3 columns of {x, y, value} to the matrix table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say we have an input table of:

```
1980, 5,  H
1980, 7,  H
1980, 11, C
1981, 1,  W
...
```

How can we convert it to a new table of:

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12
1980              H     H            C
1981  W...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your example data are in cells A2:A5 and the result table in cells A7:M9, then the following array formula entered into cell B7 and copied across to column M and down to row 9 would produce the desired result. The formula assumes that an empty string ("'") is entered into cell C1. If there are more rows in the data range, you will need to adjust the term ROW($1:$4) to the actual number of data rows.

```
  =OFFSET($C$1,SUM(($A8=$A$2:$A$5)*(B$7=$B$2:$B$5)*ROW($1:$4)),0)
```

[image: worksheet]

Since it is an array formula, it must be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, a long time ago, I solved this through a macro, but this seems ways cooler!

Comment: It is proved to work for 1000+ rows

Answer (score 1):

If each year-number pair is unique, you can plot your data using an array formula<sup>**1**</sup> across your table.

```
{=IFERROR(OFFSET($C$1,SUM((years=$E2)*(numbers=F$1)*ROW(data_to_plot))-1,0,1,1),"")}
```

Where **`years`**, **`numbers`** and **`data_to_plot`** are named ranges pointing to the first, second and third columns of your source range, respectively (as shown in the screenshot below). You don't have to use named ranges, but it'll make writing/editing the formula easier.

[image]

In the above, example, note the references (which ones are relative/absolute) & ranges and where they point.

--
**<sup>1</sup>** *Must be committed/entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>* before copying it across the rows/columns of your "matrix" table.

Comment: It might work, but I failed to make it.

Comment: It does work & I can't imagine how you could fail to make it. However, you're probably running an older version of Excel. `IFERROR` only works in MS Excel 2007 & above.